# Good open source mailserver for linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, open-source, email-server

I'm looking for a good open source Linux mailserver for a small (internet) company. Which is still updated frequently. I'm developing the website with PHP and MySQL if that's important. Anybody any idea(s)?

Thanks

Comment: can't go wrong with postfix.

Comment: `postfix` is RHEL6 default now so it isn't going anywhere. That also means a lot of enterprise support.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!     This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions).

Comment: @lain, what do you mean shopping recommendations???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix. It's very reliable, still developed and used by many mail servers. Most Linux platforms support it. Works fine with php and mysql. If not postfix, then check qmail: same same but different.

Comment: For god's sake, don't use qmail unless you have a very good reason: http://shearer.org/MTA_Comparison#qmail and that's from 5 years ago.  qmail is even more out of date now.

Comment: -1 QMail hasn't been updated in about 13 years. It's pretty much irresponsible to recommend it at this point.

Comment: Oops. I didn't know qmail was outdated. So then I only recommend postfix.

Answer (score 1):

you could use Dovecot IMAP Server.

If you need to integrate it with your website / intranet based on PHP/MySQL, you can use the class http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2351-PHP-Access-IMAP-mailboxes-without-PHP-IMAP-extension.html

Works with Postfix and EXIM, too.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Postfix and Exim are the two most common mail servers for Linux. I use Exim without any problem ever, but I thing people using Postfix don't have problem either.
Other choices include qmail. Very famous too because of its origin. A little less common.

Comment: QMail hasn't been updated in something like 13 years. I don't know why people even mention it let alone *recommend* it.

Comment: @ChrisS ...let alone roll it into default CentOS 6 VPS images like what I just got. :'(